# How to use PHP curl to fetch www.yahoo.com page?

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

Try to write a simple crawler method. When I use PHP curl to get the ***www.yahoo.com*** page, I fetch nothing. How can I fetch the page?
My code is in the following.

```
public function getWebPage($url, $timeout = 120) {
    $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, 
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.19) Gecko/20081216 Ubuntu/8.04 (hardy) Firefox/2.0.0.19",
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true, 
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $timeout,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => $timeout,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    );

    $ch      = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $err     = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg  = curl_error($ch);
    $header  = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use [Symfony Crawler and Guzzle](http://www.ymc.ch/en/webscraping-in-php-with-guzzle-http-and-symfony-domcrawler) or [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/goutte) to create a crawler instead of doing yourself something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yahoo.com runs on secure socket layer.  So add this `cURL` param to your existing set.

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER     => false,
```

and also disable the `USERAGENT`..

#### The working code.. (tested)

```
<?php

class A
{
    public function getWebPage($url, $timeout = 120) {
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
            //CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.19) Gecko/20081216 Ubuntu/8.04 (hardy) Firefox/2.0.0.19",
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $timeout,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => $timeout,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
        );

        $ch      = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        $err     = curl_errno($ch);
        $errmsg  = curl_error($ch);
        $header  = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $content;
    }
}

$a = new A;
echo $a->getWebPage('www.yahoo.com');
```

Comment: Instead of disabling SSL verification, you should rather figure out why it fails (if that's indeed the problem) and fix that. The only reason could be a missing root certificate, which is easily retrieved.

Comment: Just a question. I thought some websites check for valid user agent, can we disable it for common use cases?